# How do I remove the second and third occurrences of $ from a given string?

Tags: java, c#, c++

```
"srmbscsrm $bsc $ srmbsc $ "
```

How do I delete the second and third occurrence of the `$` symbol in the above string using string functions?

Comment: `Java`, `C#`, `C++`?  Please take a look at [ASK].

Comment: The only option I see is to get the substrings and then append them

Comment: Which language do you use in particular? You can not ask and answer the question for all of those at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
string s = "srmbscsrm $bsc $ srmbsc $";
string result = string.Empty;
char t = '$';
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (s[i] == t)
    {
        count++;
        if (count == 1)
        {
            result += s[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result += s[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Find first and remove ones after that. In C++:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string s{"srmbscsrm $bsc $ srmbsc $ "};

  auto const del = '$';
  auto const first = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), del);
  if (first != s.end())
    s.erase(std::remove(std::next(first), s.end(), del), s.end());
  std::cout << s;
}
```

Output: `srmbscsrm $bsc  srmbsc`

Answer (score 1):

A lame way to do it in Java:

```java
String a="srmbscsrm $bsc $ srmbsc $ ";
StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();
char[] x=a.toCharArray();
int first=1; // to include only first occurrence of $
for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    if(x[i]!='$') {
        str.append(x[i]);
    }   else if(x[i]=='$' && first==1) {
        str.append(x[i]);
        first++;
    }
}
System.out.println(str.toString());
```